# Adding prior belief into a neural Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am busy with a classification problem, with three classes. One of the classes is never predicted/classified. I would like to know if there s anyway to inject a prior belief into my neural network, be design or not.

My football prediction model predicts `[Draws , Home Win , Away Win]`. My classes are pretty balanced (40% , 30 % , 30%). The class `[Draw]` that accounts for 40% of the data is the one the my NN never predicts. My dataset contains 1900 samples.

I am using a deep NN with 2 to 4 hidden layers.

My code of my best model(based on training/val loss) is as follows:

```
X_all = df.copy()

train_cols = ['a_line0','a_line1','a_line2','a_line3','a_line4','a_line5',
              'a_line6','a_line7','a_line8','a_line9','a_line10','h_line0',
              'h_line1','h_line2','h_line3','h_line4','h_line5','h_line6',
              'h_line7','h_line8','h_line9','h_line10','odds0','odds1','odds2']


x = X_all[train_cols]

x_v = x.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x_v)
x = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)

y = X_all['result']
ohe = OneHotEncoder(n_values=3,categories='auto')
y = ohe.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

for lr,ep in [(0.001,300)]:
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(25, input_dim=25, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(36, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
    adam = kr.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, decay=1e-6)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=ep, batch_size=10,verbose = 0)
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    _, accuracy1 = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
    print('Testing Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100),'Train Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy1*100), 'learning rate : ', lr)
```

I apologise if the code is a bit messy.
My model also overfits by +- 16% (52% vs 68%) on this config of my network.

Comment: Have you inspected the random training split that you’re training on? It’s possible that by poor luck, you’re training on very few draws. If that was the case you could try a stratified split so that your training set is balanced equally to your validation.

Comment: I have yeah, same thing.

Comment: That's strange. My recommendation would be to try replicating this with a very simple network (no hidden layers), or even something like linear regression or a random forest from sklearn to see exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in a multi-class **single-label** setting (i.e. your labels are mutually exclusive), you should not use `sigmoid` as activation in your final layer; change it to

```
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Also, dropout should not be used by default; remove it for starters, and only add it if it improves the result.

Comment: I followed your advice, however the results remain the same. I included the dropout just to counter the overfit I observed. I forgot to mention that my dataset consist of 1900 samples. 

Do you have any other recommendations? Thank you for the edits you provided.